# Probability calculations

Tags: r, excel, math, excel-formula, probability

Cannot get my head around "probability". Assuming:

`N` <- 5 #balls in a pot 
`R` <- 3 #balls selected from the pot without putting them back 
`Z` <- 2 #correct selected from the pot

A total of ten combinations is possible:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
 [2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
 [3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5
```

When I assume that `Z` is both the numbers `1` and `2`, we count that this applies for three combinations.

I would think that the probability would be 3 / 10 = 0.3 = 30%

This is different from the result I get from Excel:

```
=HYPGEOMDIST(2;3;3;5)
```

It is also different from the result in R:

```
choose(R,Z)*choose((N-R),(R-Z))/choose(N,R)
```

Both outcomes equal 0.6 = 60%

What am I missing here please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of `Z` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in Excel (in addition to Henrik's answer)

`=COMBIN(3,2)/COMBIN(5,3)`

=3/10
 =30%

Answer (score 1):

`HYPGEOMDIST(2;3;2;5)` yields `0.3` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the computation should be:

choose(N-Z,R-Z)/choose(N,R)=choose(5-2,1)/choose(5,3)=0.3

The total is clearly choose(N,R). The number of successes is the number of ways to pick the balls other than the "correct" balls. There are N-Z balls to choose from and you must choose R-Z -- the -Z is in both because you've already chosen the correct balls, so they are taken out of the equation.